# Install Android SDK in Centos 7

Tags: centos7, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I have been struggling to install Android SDK in a CentOS 7 environment with no UI.  I have been trying to use `sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip` and `android-studio-ide-183.5452501-linux.tar.gz` from https://developer.android.com/studio and not having much luck.  It seems like there is no Android SDK directory that I can set ANDROID_HOME to.

Comment: I have the same problem. have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract android tool then install platform tools and then configure environemnt path.

`yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

`mkdir -p /opt/android-sdk-linux`

`cd /opt/android-sdk-linux`

`wget --output-document=android-sdk.zip --quiet`

`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip`

`unzip android-sdk.zip`

`rm -f android-sdk.zip`

`yes | tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

`tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" 
 "extras;google;m2repository"`

`# sudo vim /etc/profile.d/android-sdk-env.sh`

`export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux"`
`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/opt/android-sdk-linux"`
`export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"`

`# sudo source /etc/profile.d/android-sdk-env.sh`